# How to ensure Facebook users provides their emails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth, facebook-oauth

### The problem

The site I am working on is a Rails app which lets users sign in with their Facebook account.

On the Facebook Auth Dialog page, they are requested to provide basic information and email. Emails are then saved into the database.

However, recently I noticed that there are many users having an email of `nil` or `""`. I checked their permissions with the Open Graph API (`https://graph.facebook.com/#{id}/permissions`). Some of them granted the `email` permission while some didn't.

I have no idea how this could happen.

### My Experiment

#### 1

Although [the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) says:

> If you are using the Enhanced Auth Dialog, the following permissions are not user-revokable within the authentication flow.
>   If you request these permissions from the user as part of first-time authentication, **the user must grant these permissions in order to continue and authorize your application**.

On the Auth Dialog page (`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=...&display=page&next=...&response_type=code&perms=email&fbconnect=1`), I can remove the `perms=email` parameter, then email won't be requested.

If I sign in with this dialog, the app receives no email address.

#### 2

In Apps > Settings > Permissions, I try to set up some permissions I don't need. (Before I experiment this, the settings are empty).

But these settings have no effects to the authentication process.

### The question

Given the setup (Rails + Devise + Omniauth) I have, is it possible to ensure users grant email permission before sign in?

Answer (score 0):

$permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");
if( array_key_exists('email', $permissions['data'][0]) ) {
    // Permission is granted!
} else {
    // We don't have the permission
}

Comment: Hi @dythffvrb, thanks for the answer. I know the api to check the user's permissions. But couldn't the sign-in be stopped at Facebook side?